# 11.10 is not Upgrading

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

My Ubuntu 11.10 is not getting upgraded through Update Manager. It's not able to connect to the servers also. While checking for updates it will try for sometime and pop-up message as check your Internet connection. Is there any way to manually upgrade.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting alt+F2 and type `update-manager --d`